# Bot telegram didnt work on dev environment

Tags: .net, job-scheduling, core-api

i build a telegram bot and it worked perfect on my laptop but when i push it on dev environment, using github and gg cloud to build, it didnt work, i set job for it to run every 12am and 23pm.When i tesed it by let it send messages every 5mins, it worked but for the 12am it didnt.pls help me guys.
here are my job:
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new TelegramBotClient("7193708687:AAEYjPapy_e9YQWJPqOue_5f9wH1oKs_qo4"));
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
q.AddJob(opts => opts.WithIdentity("ReportJobNoon"));
q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
.ForJob("ReportJobNoon")
.WithIdentity("ReportJobNoon-trigger")
.WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 * * ?"));

```
    q.AddJob<ReportOrderEvening>(opts => opts.WithIdentity("ReportJobEvening"));
    q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
        .ForJob("ReportJobEvening")
        .WithIdentity("ReportJobEvening-trigger")
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0 23 * * ?"));
});
```

and im sure there'r nothing wrong with my code becaues it worked perfect on my local

hope you guys help me fix that